# Python logging strange issue

Tags: python, logging, popen, file-writing

I have a strange issue where logs are not written to log file.
I can't post all the code here, but what I'm doing is the following:

I have a logger with file handler and then I execute some script (which I get as input).
All the logs that I'm doing after executing the script are disappearing from the log file

```
logging.info('Before execution')
# execute user script
popen(...)
logging.info('After execution')
```

The 'After execution' message is not written to the log
The strange thing is that when I run `tail -f <log>` int the terminal, then I can see the `'After execution'` message. But when I open the log file to see its content, I don't see this message.

When I close the file handler before logging `'After execution'` then the message is written to the log as expected.

What could be the issue? I guess it's something with the user script that I'm executing in `popen(...)`, but I have no idea what this script is doing. When I run some simple script instead, then everything works as expected. What could be the issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Popen does not wait for the script to finish so try to use a wait before the logging call, otherwise it will execute the logging as soon as possible and most likely before the script has time to finish.

```py
logging.info('Before execution')
process = Popen(...)
process.wait()
logging.info('After execution')
```

Comment: I do wait for the process to finish. The log message doesn't appear in the log file at all